# Passing the return value from my negmax method

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe, negamax

I've been working on this for a few days, at least.  Testing seems to show the correct value is being returned.  My problem is being able to grab the `best_move` value and have it print out.  I set up the `suggested_move` method and try to use `return suggested_move(best_move)` but it triggers the method for every level back up the tree.  Also it returns the wrong value, which I'm guessing is because it's stopping before depth is back to 0.

In my minimax I had a similar setup the difference being the depth was incremented (not decremented) on successive calls.  Point being I was able to say `if depth == 0 p best_move`.  So I'm scratching my head because using that same conditional I get a nil class error in this code.

```
 @board = ["X","O","O","X","X","","","O",""]

def available_spaces
   @board.map.with_index {|a, i| a == "" ? i+1 : nil}.compact
end

def suggested_move(move)
  p "Suggested move: #{move}"
end

def full?
  @board.all?{|token| token == "X" || token == "O"}
end

def suggested_move(move)
  p "Move: #{move}"
end

def bestmove(board, depth=0, best_score = {})
return 0 if full?
return 1 if won?

best = -Float::INFINITY

  available_spaces.each do |space|
  @board[space-1] = current_player
  best_score[space] = -bestmove(@board, depth-1, {})
  @board[space-1] = ""  
end
 p best_score
  if best_score.max_by {|key,value| value }[1] > best
    best = best_score.max_by {|key,value| value }[1]
    best_move = best_score.max_by {|key,value| value }[0]
  end
  return best_move
end 

bestmove(@board)
```

Comment: Not sure I'm completely following, also you have two suggested_move functions. In one of the functions why cant you `p bestmove(@board)` to print the result?

Comment: Yes, usually if the -score is higher, the -score is returned (as opposed to a move) I couldn't make that work, still working on that one.   Anyway, you are right I could do the p best_move(@board)

Comment: I just edited my post and removed the `if / else` statement.